# Error trying to update to using SignInManager in Identity 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to update my login feature to using this line:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

However I get the following error:

```
Error   1   Using the generic type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInManager<TUser,TKey>' requires 2 type arguments
```

Before this I had to install a few nuget packages so I think something merely has been missed somewhere, but this is way out my my league! Any help would be hugely appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: im supplying 4 arguments to passwordSignInAsync though, not SignInManager. See http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity
Just under the heading "Requiring a user to have a validated email account"
Thanks!

Comment: The answer below is correct. You want to use something like this. SignInManager<User, int> signInManager. Also you are trying to sign in using the email not the username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply the types as well.  Like this:

```
var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync<IdentityUser, string>(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

`IdentityUser` may be `ApplicationUser` if you've been following the example code.

Also, The examples you're looking at are based on the microsoft.aspnet.identity.samples nuget package.  This would put an `ApplicationSignInManager` in the identityConfig.cs which extends `SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>` and then a public `SignInManager` property in the `Accountcontroller`.  Its this property that the examples use - hence why it doesn't have the type requirement.