# ApplicationSignInManager class throws invalid cast exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is the code taken from the MVC5 account controller class ( this is created as a template when you set up a asp.net project)
However when i pass in the following parameter to this line of code

model.UserName="User1", model.password="Password1",model.RememberMe=false, shouldLockout=false

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
```

it throws an exception saying

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

What i don't understand is why does the line of code above thinks the parameter is int when  all the parameter are 
either string or boolean.

Anyone up for help? Thanks for advance.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);   

    }
```

Code for LoginViewModel Class

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It throws this error because you are sending string as parameter but it needs Int32.

Comment: It doesnt as i checked the type of the parameter. model.UserName(string) model.password(String) , model.RememberMe(bool) , shouldLockOut(bool)

Comment: is your Username, password is in int, try changing it to string first.

Comment: both are string that can accomodate alphanumeric characters.

Comment: i have added the code for the model class

Comment: The code won't compile if the types are wrong (unless you're using `dynamic` and it which case you're not going to get an `InvalidCastException` anyway). Look at the stack trace: it's probably happening somewhere inside ASP.NET Identity. You can provide your own validators etc. Perhaps one of those is wrong.

Comment: @Sike12 it needs debugging man, try to see what model.UserName and model.Password is returning...

Comment: The answer to [Error trying to update to using SignInManager in Identity 2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103900/error-trying-to-update-to-using-signinmanager-in-identity-2-0) may help

Comment: Thanks @ta.speot.is i'll look at your point.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i saw that link perhaps might need to do that update.

Comment: @CodingDefined i Checked the parameters and their values both are returning string characters.

Answer (score 4):

In attempting to resolve a very similar error (Unable to cast object of type system.guid to type system.string) for the same scenario, I traced the problem to the data types that had been used for the key columns of two Roles tables (AspNetRoles and AspNetUserRoles). These needed to be of type **nvarchar**, not uniqueidentifier.

The SQL query behind PasswordSignInAsync gathers data from AspNetUsers, AspNetUserRoles, AspNetUserClaims and AspNetUserLogins so I suggest you check that your key column types across all of these tables match what the expected entities that this data will be mapped to. As far as I'm aware, these should be as follows:

> AspNetUsers > [Id] NVARCHAR (128)
>
> AspNetRoles > [Id] NVARCHAR (128)
>
> AspNetUserRoles > [UserId] NVARCHAR (128), [RoleId] NVARCHAR (128)
>
> AspNetUserClaims > [Id] INT
>
> AspNetUserLogins > [UserId] NVARCHAR (128)

Comment: i'll try it out and let you know @sharptooth. It looks promising though.